# OpenVZ to VMware / Hyper-v / KVM convertion

Tags: vmware-vsphere, migration, openvz, convert

```
vzctl - 4.1
guest os - altlinux 5 (2.6.32)
filesystem - simfs
no ploop
```

I need to convert/migrate/relocate a bunch of containers from legacy openvz server to vmware/kvm/hyper-v system.

I tried to create vm and install the same altlinux 5, after that I booted from the systemrescuecd, mounted the disk and tried to copy data with rsync to my fresh vm - no luck. When i try to start vm the system doesnt load, just stuck without any error.

Also this guide (https://communities.vmware.com/message/1719787#1719787) doesnt help me. When i boot from livecd - i can`t mount disk (no filesystem error)

What is the best way to mirate openvz containers to vms?

Comment: What do you mean no luck ? Did you try rsync --delete --exclude /boot ? The list of excludes would need to be tuned, but this is the right approach..